# How to stop consuming after an amount of time of no messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to close my connection after the queue hasn't been active for 5 minutes. I have:

```
  ch.consume(receivingQueue, async function (msg) {
    if (msg !== null) {
      console.log(msg.content.toString()));
    }
  });
```

I read about [Channel.cancel()](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_cancel) but i'm just not quite sure where to insert that into the flow here since the process is just sitting and waiting for a new message, and I'm not sure where to get the `consumerTag` as it is not in the `msg` variable.

Comment: Consumer tag is the return value of the `consume` function. Have you debugged/stepped through this code? What happens after the first line you have here? Statement should go to the next line. Try setting it equal to something (e.g. `let consumerTag = ch.consume(...`

Comment: Also, the real question is "why would you want to do this?"

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but logic is as follows. setTimeout is set to close connection after 5 mins on every message. If a new message arrives the old timer is cleared by the new message and a new timer is recreated. otherwise the connection closes after 5 mins

```
 const closeConnection = function () {
       ch.close()
 }
 let timer = setTimeout(()=>{}, 0); //initial timer for cleartimeout Maybe refactor this?  

 ch.consume(receivingQueue, async function (msg) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(closeConnection, 300000)
  if (msg !== null) {
   console.log(msg.content.toString()));
  }
 });
```